# Ubuntu Windows installer, no boot option

Tags: installation, windows

Hi I've downloaded and ran the Wubi but when it ask me to reboot I do, but it just boots up Window XP. I don't get any option to select ubuntu.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I found the problem, needed to tick the option 'time to display list of operating systems' in the startup and recovery panel in system properties

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you boot from Wubi disk/dvd just created.
Check the boot order! 
Enter bios and change boot order.